# What information does a developer get from apple about each user that buys an app in the appstore?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Does anyone know what end user information a developer receives from Apple regarding a purchase of their application in the app store?

Do they receive the end users full name, the unique identifier of their iPhone/iPod touch, or possibly their email address?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None of the above.  All you get is a tally of how many people purchased your app, on what day, and from what country.  Any additional data would have to be gathered from directly in the app, that is, the app would have to "phone home".

Comment: Also Apple does tell you how many free updates are downloaded vs. how many new purchases there are.

Comment: Plus any promo code downloads (although not which promo codes were used ...), any refunded apps and the price in the countries' currency.