# What information can I get about my iOS customer

Tags: ios, app-store, privacy

I want to know what identifying information I will be able to send to my web server from my iOS app.

I have searched the Apple Developer website to answer this question but I cannot seem to find anything.

This is the type of information I am interested in:

- Unique Identifier
- First Name
- Last Name
- Email Address
- Age
- Address

Comment: Apple were in deep trouble if you could do that.

Comment: Why do you think you need this info?

Comment: @rmaddy: At a minimum (Unique Identifier) to track usage and performance metrics.

Comment: Look at the docs for `UIDevice`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Is this my answer (from iOS documentation): Use the UUID method of the NSUUID class to create a UUID and write it to the user defaults database.

Comment: Why not use `UIDevice identifierForVendor`?

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes that's much better. Thanks. I'm new to Objective C and the method signature threw me off. Marking you as correct. I realize that you have 65K on SO but if you post UIDevice.identifierForVendor in your answer below it might help the next newb.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What information does a developer get from apple about each user that buys an app in the appstore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445444/what-information-does-a-developer-get-from-apple-about-each-user-that-buys-an-ap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no information at all about the user of your app available through any public API.

If you want anything you need to provide a form in your app that the user can fill in.

And any app asking for such information will quickly be deleted by a user unless the information is critical to the app's functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't get any of that information from the system directly. If you need that info, you should ask the user to create an account for your application and have them enter the info. That's the best way to get the users permission and not get into hot water with privacy issues.